# Asymptotic complexity of this summation?

Tags: math, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Just started a new course (data struct) and having some trouble with a question:

For what F(n) function is this true?

[image: Picture]

My direction is that it should happen when The N exponent is 1 or less, because that will match the definition of thetha as the function will be closer and bounded by C1*F(n) and C2*F(n), but im not sure about that. Thanks!

Comment: I think this question would better be asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or at [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

> 0n + 1n + 2n + ... + n·n
>
> = n(0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n)
>
> = n(n(n+1)/2)

with that last step following from Gauss's sum. Therefore, the summation is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: This is a great answer. +1 I would have just shown that by throwing the first half of `1+2+3...+n` I block it from below by n^3, then increase all the items to n+n+n+...+n to show it is blocked  by an upper bound of n^3. Then deduce it is `tetha(n^3)`

Comment: That approach definitely works, though I've found that just knowing a few handy sums here and there is often really useful for simplifying things like these.

Answer (score -1):

I'm studying the same course right now, and I think that if you apply the next rule it might work out.

```
lim n->inf    f(x) / g(x) = c ,
```